# Visual Studio Code always starts in some kind of 'inspection' mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Every time I start VS Code on Mac it is in some weird 'inspection' mode or sth like that (See first picture). It doesn't show the cursor after a character but instead it selects the last character. But unlike how this mode normally works I can't type anything. It just makes some weird actions when I press the keys e.g. jumping to a different word in the next row. I can 'fix' this by pressing shift + I and after that I can type just fine (see second picture).
BUT I have to do this for every file in my project and every time I close a file or close the IDE I have to do this again next time. It is so annoying. I already reinstalled VSC twice. The current version and the LTS version but it did not fix this.

I already use VS Code on Windows but I don't have the problem there.
It also doesn't matter which project I open it happens every time. I just created a new react app with "npx create-react-app react-test" and opened this folder in VSC. Still the same problem.

How can I fix this?

[image: Weird mode]

[image: Normal mode]

Comment: that is really weird, you should open a bug with Microsoft.

Comment: Seems like you've installed some sort of `vi` addon. Uninstall it.

Comment: I don't have any extensions installed. It's a clean install of VSC.

Comment: Seems you *have* extension installed (Prettier isn't OOB VS Code). A clean install of VS code won't remove any local per-user data (at least on Windows, maybe it's different on Mac). You should clear any `~/.vscode` folder to be sure there's personal data. Also `code --help` show some flags you can try (`code --disable-extensions`)

Comment: @SteveB Ty that worked. Instead of just uninstalling it I deleted it with "AppCleaner" and after a new installation it was working fine again